# In C# with CSOM, How can I copy a file from a known location to a known Folder?

Tags: c#, copy, sharepoint-online, csom, shared-directory

I have one function which uses `SearchExecutor` finds to find the path of a specified file, which returns a string like.

> https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/DevelopementTestingSite/Shared Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=43

I have another function which creates and returns a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder`.

Give:

1. The filename,
2. The file location, and
3. The Folder.

How can I copy the file to the folder?

If it helps, the ServerRelativePath has been initialized on the Folder with:

```
            Folder itemFolder = folderItem.Folder;
            context.Load(itemFolder, folder => folder.ServerRelativePath);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            return itemFolder;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSOM `File.CopyTo` method or `File.CopyToUsingPath` method to copy a file to another location.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt827708(v=office.15)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee542558(v=office.15)

It's easy to get the file instance via the file location info.

- [Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee539363(v=office.15))

BR

Comment: Cheers for the answer.  CopyTo did the trick, though the answer on sharepoint.stackexchange.com (which I only just learned of) was more useful:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287125/in-c-with-csom-how-can-i-copy-a-file-from-a-known-location-to-a-known-folder/287160?noredirect=1#comment305185_287160